# Can you self-sponsor a UK Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, applications, visa-sponsors

I have been invited for army assessment in UK.

With no parents (deceased) and no rich family member. Currently running my business, I have properties in my name and I'm married.

Can my visa be accepted if it's self-sponsored and I include all documents like business regstration, bank statement , deed, utility bills, blueboob, marriege certificate, my 2 children birth certificate and a friend who is in UK as my mentor?

Booking of a hotel has been made in UK for me. Lastly I add my brothers national ID's (they don't have any passports).

Comment: It is generally better to be able to show that you can afford the trip yourself and meet the eligibility requirements without the need for a sponsor. So if you can show a credible reason for the application, sufficient funds, strong ties to home and a decent travel history your application stands as good a chance of success as any other. But no-one can say for sure.